# UWP System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied

Tags: c#, uwp

```
using(WebClient cln = new WebClient()) {
    try {
        FileSavePicker picker = new FileSavePicker();
        picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("PNG File", new List < string > () {
            ".png"
        });
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;

        var file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();

        cln.DownloadFile("https://i.redd.it/o8rz4s0lxp021.png", file.Path);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

When i start this file creates but it throws `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` and the file is corrupted. Any ideas about what is wrong?

Comment: Nobody never reads exception messages :( _"Access to the path is denied"_ means that you do not have access to specified path. As you said `UWP` - have you read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) document?

Comment: It seems you are trying to start download file before `PickSaveFileAsynccompleted`. Use `await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);` then download content

Comment: I changed path to `Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;` but it's still denied.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have Synchronization problem here. You should make sure that `FileSavePicker` job is done before you download content since you are trying to update file asynchronously (`await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();`). To do so you can use [`FileUpdateStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker)

```
using (WebClient cln = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        FileSavePicker picker = new FileSavePicker();
        picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("PNG File", new List<string>() { ".png" });
        picker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;

        var file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
          // Prevent updates to the remote version of the file until we finish making changes and call CompleteUpdatesAsync.
        CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file);
        // write to file
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, file.Name);
        // Let Windows know that we're finished changing the file so the other app can update the remote version of the file.
        // Completing updates may require Windows to ask for user input.
        FileUpdateStatus status = await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file);
        if (status == FileUpdateStatus.Complete)
        {
            cln.DownloadFile("https://i.redd.it/o8rz4s0lxp021.png", file.Path);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok i fixed it by changing this:

`cln.DownloadFile("https://i.redd.it/o8rz4s0lxp021.png", file.Path);` 
to BackgroundDownloarder:

```
BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
DownloadOperation download = downloader.CreateDownload(new Uri("https://i.redd.it/o8rz4s0lxp021.png"), file);
await download.StartAsync();
```

Comment: Have you tried my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59858770/5519709), it seems similar sync issue?

Comment: i have tried it did not work with DownloadFile() but BackgroundDownloader do not work without it so thank you ^^